# MongoError: Found multiple array filters with the same top-level field name

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

folks. I'm working in Node.js with a MongoDB collection that has a field that is an array of objects, like so:

```
{_id: 'someIdNumber',
text: 'some text',
replies: [{_id: 'someReplyId', replyText: 'some reply text', password: 'somePassword'}, {...}]
```

I'm trying to update the `replyText` field of the `replies` array using the `$[<identifier>]` array update operator as shown in the MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/ What I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
db.collection('collectionName').updateOne(
                { _id: ObjectID('whateverId') },
                { $set: { "replies.$[elem].replyText": "new text" } },
                {
                  arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.body.reply_id)}, {"elem.password": 'whateverPassword}]
                },
                (err, data) => {console.log('hooray, it worked')}
```

This throws an error, `MongoError: Found multiple array filters with the same top-level field name elem`. If I get rid of one of my `arrayFilters`, this fixes the error, but obviously at the expense of my filtering conditions.

The MongoDB documentation's example of this process, (I've shortened the collection `students2` to a single document,) is as follows:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 100, "std" : 4 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 100, "std" : 6 }
   ]
}


db.students2.update(
   { },
   { $inc: { "grades.$[elem].std" : -1 } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.grade": { $gte: 80 }, "elem.std": { $gt: 5 } } ], multi: true }
)
```

The syntax is a tiny bit different because the documentation is using the Mongo shell method, not Node.js, but otherwise, it looks to me like I'm doing what the documentation says to do. I'm using `updateOne` and not `update` because I only want to update one document, and I'm not using `multi` for the same reason.
Any insight on how I could get this to work with both `arrayFilters` intact would be much appreciated.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: The syntax is a bit error-prone, I'm afraid. Could it be you wanted to express this:

`arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.body.reply_id), "elem.password": 'whateverPassword}]`

instead of:

`arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.body.reply_id)}, {"elem.password": 'whateverPassword}]`
                
                
:-)

Comment: Wow, big facepalm moment. Totally misread that as an array of objects, but you’re right, there’s definitely just one object in there with two entries. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I still have same issue @LuosRestil

Comment: Yes, for me it was just a syntax error, as pointed out by typesafe. So what I had was ```{
                  arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.body.reply_id)}, {"elem.password": 'whateverPassword}]
                }```, but what I should have had was ```{
                  arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": ObjectID(req.body.reply_id), "elem.password": 'whateverPassword}]
                }```

Answer (score 18):

Got it! Unfortunately I cannot upvote the question/comment hence adding here for others to benefit. Thanks @LuosRestil and @typesafe for getting me to the fix. I had the same syntax error where I tried to add multiple expressions for the same field in the array for the arrayFilters. It should be once expression per field.

WRONG:

```
arrayFilters: [
  { "elemA.<fieldName1>": "value1" },
  { "elemA.<fieldName2>": "value2" },
  { "elemA.<fieldName3>": "value3" }
];
```

CORRECT:

```
arrayFilters: [
  {
    "elemA.<fieldName1>": "value1",
    "elemA.<fieldName2>": "value2",
    "elemA.<fieldName3>": "value3"
  }
];
```